# How to calculate the sum of values generated in a bash until loop?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I eficiently add the output of the until loop in the following bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash

fcf=2000
g1=0.05
ny1=5

gip=0

until [ $gip -eq $ny1 ]; do
        awk "BEGIN {print $fcf * (1 + $g1)^$gip}"
        ((gip++))
done
```

The output when I run the loop is:

```
2000
2100
2205
2315.25
2431.01
```

However what I want to get is the sum of the values generated in the output which would be 11051.26.

Comment: You're already using `awk` for arithmetic. Consider porting the entire loop (entire script?) to `awk`. If you need to improve precision then read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/579975/108618).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using awk anyways, why not using awk all the way?

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    fcf=2000
    g1=0.05
    ny1=5
    gip=0
    
    sum=0
    
    while(gip != ny1){
        sum+=(fcf * (1 + g1) ^ gip)
        gip++
    }
    printf("%.2f\n", sum)
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works fine bobby, I do however need a solution in bash as this calculation is only part of a much larger script.

Comment: You could pipe your output to awk again with `awk 'BEGIN { sum=0 } { sum+=$0 } END { prinf("%.2f", sum) }'`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096259/bash-command-to-sum-a-column-of-numbers) - also check responses!

Answer (score 0):

I have considered both input from Kamil and bobby and come up with this answer which works:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN {
    fcf=2000
    g1=0.05
    ny1=5
    gip=0
    
    sum=0
    
    while(gip != ny1){
        sum+=(fcf * (1 + g1) ^ gip)
        gip++
    }
    printf("%.2f", sum)
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

to circumvent floating point arithmetics I changed the formula a little bit. in addition there is no need to run external commands like awk.

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fcf=200000
g1=5
ny1=5
gip=0

until [ $gip -eq $ny1 ]; do
        X=$(( $fcf*(100+$g1)**$gip/100**$gip ))
        printf "%.2f\n" ${X}e-2
        let SUM=SUM+X
        let gip=gip+1
done

printf "%.2f\n" ${SUM}e-2
```

output:

```
2000.00
2100.00
2205.00
2315.25
2431.01
11051.26
```

HTH
Stefan K.